# Access to database zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, mysqli, adapter

I want to access to database "mysql", I read that we can define the db adapter and db configurations by writing these lines in application.ini file

```
resources.db.adapter = MYSQLI
resources.db.params.host = localhost
resources.db.params.username = root
resources.db.params.password =123456
resources.db.params.dbname = visits_db
```

I want to get the **$db** object in order to use in for executing sql statements

```
    $db->insert("inspection_visits_tb",
            $insepctionVisitData = array(
        'day' => $visit->getDay(),
        'date' => $visit->getDate(),
        'target' => $visit->getTarget()
    ));
```

I want to get it from the application.ini file not like this

```
require_once 'Zend/Db.php';
    $db = Zend_Db::factory("MYSQLI",
                    array(
                        "host" => "localhost",
                        "dbname" => "visits_db",
                        "username" => "root",
                        "password" => "123456")
    );
```

because I want to define the db adapter in one place only. What should I do to get the **$db** object??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up the `db` resource in `application.ini` like you were.  Add the `isDefaultAdapter` option.

```
resources.db.adapter = "MYSQLI"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = "123456"
resources.db.params.dbname = "visits_db"
resources.db.isDefaultAdapter = true
```

Then to get the `$db` object...

#### In Bootstrap.php

```
protected function _initDb()
{
    $this->bootstrap('db');
    $db = $this->getResource('db');
    Zend_Registry::set('db', $db);
}
```

#### From Somewhere else w/out using Registry

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
```

#### Using Zend_Db_Table

```
$table  = new Zend_Db_Table('bugs');
$select = $table->select()...
```

See also [ZF Quickstart](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html), [Zend_Db_Table](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.introduction), [Zend_Db_Select](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html) for more examples.

Comment: I make put the _initDb() in the bootstrap.php inside the module, but this exception occur, "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception' with message 'Circular resource dependency detected' in E:\GCC\ZendFramework-1.11.11\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php:662"

Comment: It works without making any configurations in the bootstrap.php, and adding this line in any somewhere  $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();