# Starting with zend db (mysql)

Tags: database, zend-framework2, zend-db

I am new in zend framework 2 and have started my project in Zend Framework. Installation , creating modules and controllers are working fine. Now i am going to work with database connectivity & fetching data. I have read [this tutorial](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.db.sql.html) and it seems fine for me but i don't know how to start? , where to put these lines of codes? or in which files i have to work?

For example my structure is like [this](http://www.framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html) and i want to connect to database via [Zend Db](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.db.sql.html).

Your help will be really appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can visit for more help : http://zf2cheatsheet.com

Comment: thanks @Arvind, but still i don't understand what is "Doctrine" module and should i need to use this? 
I want to connect db via "Mysqli: The ext/mysqli driver" driver. Can you please help me that what configuration are required to make this working fine.

Comment: Please first use normal way of database connection as per ZF2 documentation. Doctrine is an ORM and used as a middle layer between your application and database. Please refer this example for learning the database connection in ZF2 : https://github.com/akrabat/zf2-tutorial

Comment: For mysqli, refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19062333/zend-framwork-2-mysqli-connection-configuration-and-testing-example

Comment: AbstractTableGateway supports joins. Apply join rules as per ZF2 documentation

Comment: Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578891/access-to-database-zend-framework

Comment: I have tried Mysqli reference but it did not work for me. Here are my configurations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19062333/zend-framwork-2-mysqli-connection-configuration-and-testing-example?answertab=active#tab-top